# Splitting single row to multiple unique rows Pandas Permutations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem where I have to split one row into 8 combinations of rows.

Example I have 8 columns -- first 6 belonging to each face of coin. and last two any dummy columns. As shown below(this is the old df)

```
Date, Coin1_Face_1, Coin1_Face_2, Coin2_Face_1, Coin2_Face_2, Coin3_Face_1, Coin3_Face_2, Random1, Random2

1-Jan   H   T   H   T   H   T   X   Y
2-Jan   P   Q   P   Q   P   Q   A   B
```

I want to reduce number of columns but increase number of rows as shown below(this should be the new_df):

```
Date, Coin_1, Coin_2, Coin_3, Random1, Random2
1-Jan   H   H   H   X   Y
1-Jan   H   H   T   X   Y
1-Jan   H   T   H   X   Y
1-Jan   H   T   T   X   Y
1-Jan   T   H   H   X   Y
1-Jan   T   H   T   X   Y
1-Jan   T   T   H   X   Y
1-Jan   T   T   T   X   Y
2-Jan   P   P   P   A   B
2-Jan   P   P   Q   A   B
2-Jan   P   Q   P   A   B
2-Jan   P   Q   Q   A   B
2-Jan   Q   P   P   A   B
2-Jan   Q   P   Q   A   B
2-Jan   Q   Q   P   A   B
2-Jan   Q   Q   Q   A   B
```

Can anyone pls help.

Comment: Do you want something like: `pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Coin1', 'Coin2', 'Coin3'], i='Date', j='Index', sep='_', suffix='\w+')`? I think you have too many rows represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pd.wide_to_long` and I am not sure about your row expansion, you either have to many or to few rows in your expected output.  Please explain how to expand.

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,['Coin1', 'Coin2', 'Coin3'], ['Date', 'Random1', 'Random2'], 'j', '_', '.*').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
|    | Date   | Random1   | Random2   | j      | Coin1   | Coin2   | Coin3   |
|---:|:-------|:----------|:----------|:-------|:--------|:--------|:--------|
|  0 | 1-Jan  | X         | Y         | Face_1 | H       | H       | H       |
|  1 | 1-Jan  | X         | Y         | Face_2 | T       | T       | T       |
|  2 | 2-Jan  | A         | B         | Face_1 | P       | P       | P       |
|  3 | 2-Jan  | A         | B         | Face_2 | Q       | Q       | Q       |
```

---

Try:

```
from itertools import combinations

df_m = pd.wide_to_long(df,['Coin1', 'Coin2', 'Coin3'], ['Date', 'Random1', 'Random2'], 'j', '_', '.*')

def f(g):
    g = g.reset_index(level=3, drop=True)
    indx = g.index.drop_duplicates()
    data = list(combinations(g.to_numpy().flatten('F'), 3))
    return (pd.DataFrame(data, 
                         columns=['Coin1', 'Coin2', 'Coin3'], 
                         index =indx.repeat(len(data)))
              .drop_duplicates())
    

df_out = df_m.groupby(level=[0,1,2], as_index=False).apply(f).reset_index().drop('level_0', axis=1)  
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
     Date Random1 Random2 Coin1 Coin2 Coin3
0   1-Jan       X       Y     H     T     H
1   1-Jan       X       Y     H     T     T
2   1-Jan       X       Y     H     H     T
3   1-Jan       X       Y     H     H     H
4   1-Jan       X       Y     T     H     T
5   1-Jan       X       Y     T     H     H
6   1-Jan       X       Y     T     T     H
7   1-Jan       X       Y     T     T     T
8   2-Jan       A       B     P     Q     P
9   2-Jan       A       B     P     Q     Q
10  2-Jan       A       B     P     P     Q
11  2-Jan       A       B     P     P     P
12  2-Jan       A       B     Q     P     Q
13  2-Jan       A       B     Q     P     P
14  2-Jan       A       B     Q     Q     P
15  2-Jan       A       B     Q     Q     Q
```

Comment: For 3 coins and each coin having two faces --- we can see it like 2^3 = 8 unique combinations, rest rows being static

Comment: @phewww_ See upate...

Comment: Second one worked... :) I tried doing same using dicts.... was not very proficient with pandas, plus, the syntax errors n pandas are very confusing.... :) Thanks for your efforts @Scott (m using your idea instead since it looks much cleaner than using dicts) :)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) and [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) can help with the reshaping and row generation ; [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) transforms to long form, while [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) introduces missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_longer(
    column_names = "Coin*", 
    names_to = ".value", 
    names_pattern = "([A-Za-z]+\d)_*", 
    sort_by_appearance=True)
.complete(
    'Coin1','Coin2','Coin3', 
     by = ['Date', 'Random1', 'Random2'])
)

     Date Random1 Random2 Coin1 Coin2 Coin3
0   1-Jan       X       Y     H     H     H
1   1-Jan       X       Y     H     H     T
2   1-Jan       X       Y     H     T     H
3   1-Jan       X       Y     H     T     T
4   1-Jan       X       Y     T     H     H
5   1-Jan       X       Y     T     H     T
6   1-Jan       X       Y     T     T     H
7   1-Jan       X       Y     T     T     T
8   2-Jan       A       B     P     P     P
9   2-Jan       A       B     P     P     Q
10  2-Jan       A       B     P     Q     P
11  2-Jan       A       B     P     Q     Q
12  2-Jan       A       B     Q     P     P
13  2-Jan       A       B     Q     P     Q
14  2-Jan       A       B     Q     Q     P
15  2-Jan       A       B     Q     Q     Q
```

The `.value` in [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) determines which part of the columns stay as headers. The [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function simply combines and introduces new rows based on the `by` grouping of `Date`, `Random1` and `Random2`